# Dismiss keyboard when EditText loses focus

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have an EditText that I want to control the keyboard. When the EditText has focus the keyboard should appear, then as soon as I click on any other view, I want the keyboard to disappear. I try the following code but it did work

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you still having the issue? Let me know if you need help with it still.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your outermost layout is `RelativeLayout`(You can do the similar thing for others as well), you can do something like following:

```
private RelativeLayout layout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //....
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourOutermostLayout);
    onTapOutsideBehaviour(layout);
}   

private void onTapOutsideBehaviour(View view) {
    if(!(view instanceof EditText) || !(view instanceof Button)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(YourCurrentActivity.this);
                return false;
            }

        });
    }
}


\\Function to hide keyboard
private static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

In `onTapOutsideBehaviour` function here, other that your `EditText` and `Button` views, if user clicks anywhere else, it will hide the keyboard. If you have any complex custom layout, you can exclude other views on which if user clicks, it does not hide the keyboard.

It worked for me. Hope it helps you.